# RegEx: Capture Word immediately between certain text and the opened parenthesis and closed parenthesis

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm not really expert in regex especially the hard one.
I want the string which reside between parentheses and after word "index" .

```
"(NO3)  index(doc.id(), doc.description)  index (doc.id)"
```

would return

```
"[ 'doc.id(), doc.description' ,  'doc.id' ]"
```

what I have done so far
https://jsfiddle.net/asjbcvve/

Comment: That pattern looks impossible to do in one pass...is there a reason why you must keep the parenthesis of `doc.id()`?

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/asjbcvve/2/

Comment: Is the trailing `)` always followed with whitespace/end string, or can there be such a `)` in the middle of the match?

Comment: only difficulty here are parentheses inside matched string. If max number of nested parentheses is known, it's doable (I'm working on it now). But if there can be infinite nesting, without recursive regex I don't see a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parentheses inside matching string can make this hard. Recursive regex will match that, but not all regex engines implements it. JS for example doesn't (PCRE does)

#### regex with recursion

This doesn't work in JS and many other regex engines

```
index\s*\((([^\(\)]*(\([^\(\)]*\g<2>\))?)*)
```

#### regex without recursion with 1 nested parenthesis

```
index\s*\((([^\(\)]*(\([^\(\)]*\))?)*)
```

They both catch what you want in group 1.

#### Example:

```js
var rx = /index\s*\((([^\(\)]*(\([^\(\)]*\))?)*)/g;   //works with 1 nested parentheses
var rx_recursion = /index\s*\((([^\(\)]*(\([^\(\)]*\g<2>\))?)*)/g; //works with any number of nested parentheses, but JS regex engine doesn't suppoorts recursion
var res = [], m;
var s = "(NO3)  index(doc.id(s)(), doc.description)  index (doc.id) index(nestet.doesnt.work((())))";
while ((m=rx.exec(s)) !== null) {
  res.push(m[1]);
}
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(res, 0, 4) + "</pre>";
```

#### Regex explanation

```
index\s*         - Match literal 'index' followed by any number of white characters
\(               - Match literal openning parenthesis character
(                - Group 1
  (              - Group 2
    [^\(\)]*     - Match anything that is not parentheses
    (            - Group 3
      \(         - Match literal opening parenthesis
      [^\(\)]*   - Match anything that is not parentheses
      \g<1>      - Recursively match group 1
      \)         - Match literal closing parenthesis
    )?           - End group 3, match it one or more times
   )*            - End group 2, match it zero or more times
)                - End group 1
```

If you need to match multiple nested parentheses but engine of your choice doesn't support recursion, just replace \g<1> with literal of whole group 2. Repeat as many times as many nested parentheses you expect to appear in string.